# Retrieving mysql connection strings from app.config?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection-string, app-config

How can I call the connection string by name from an app.config file in my vb.net program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Y0)